# React create app - How do you import a nested component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using React create app and I understand how to import a component into my main app which is called app.js.
What I do not understand is how I import a component in a component which is then imported in app.js (nested component).
In my app.js file, I have a component called Portfolio. In my portfolio.js file, I have a component called Language. Is it even possible to nest components with React create app? Because it does not seem to work.

This is what I tried to do:

In my app.js file :

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Portfolio from './components/portfolio';    
import "./css/styles.css"


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
      <h1>My beautiful title</h1>

      </header>
      <Portfolio />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my portfolio.js file :

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Language from './components/language';
class Portfolio extends Component {

      render() {

        return (
          <div className="portfolio">
         <Language/>
            <h1>My protfolio</h1>


          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Portfolio;
```

And in language.js I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Language extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
<div>Switch language</div>
      );
  }
}

export default Language;
```

In my browser, I keep getting the following error:

> "./src/components/portfolio.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   './components/language' in
>   'C:\Users\mluce\exercice-react\src\components'"

My language.js file is definitely sitting in my components folder. I do not understand why I get this error?

Comment: If language is in the same directory as components, try `import Language from './language';`

Comment: What's your folder structure like? Could you show a screenshot? If your Language.js is on the same level as Portfolio, you don't need to do `./component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `portfolio.js`:

```js
import Language from './language';
```